# Update PK in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mariadb

Does anyone can help me?

I need to update several columns named "ID" from MariaDB, but how can I do it?

I tried some like UPDATE glpi_tickets SET id=id+1000 WHILE id>2288, but while doens't work.

Can anyone help me?

Thnsk!

Answer (score 1):

WHILE is not a SQL command, you probably mean WHERE.

However, it is highly likely that you won’t be able to update a PK as most DBMSs don’t allow this. Instead you would have to insert the new records and delete the existing records